# Start application with VBS whos path is different between users

Tags: vbscript, scripting

All,  I am attempting to script the start of an application whose path is different between each user.  Is there any way to find the true path of the app (per user) and then start the program with the scripting below?

Also, what is the best way to run the application as the logged in user i.e. `%username%`.  I have tried the scripting below (for this issue), but doesn't seem to work.

```
on error resume next
theDir = "C:\Users\" & createobject("wscript.shell").expandenvironmentstrings("%username%") & "\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZJVRE3RK.4TQ\VLGML47Q.TPN\2rin..tion_5bfb425a74ceb3d8_0003.0004_c52ddbfe44f7690b"

theCmd = "2RingIPPSClient.exe"

Set objSh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objSh.CurrentDirectory = theDir

objSh.Run theCmd
```

Comment: the part of the path to the app that changes between users is the: ZJVRE3RK.4TQ\VLGML47Q.TPN\2rin..tion_5bfb425a74ceb3d8_0003.0004_c52ddbfe44f7690b" above

Comment: So you mean that the fixed part is `%userprofile%\Appdata\Local\2.0\    and  2RingIPPSClient.exe`  and between those parts are variables from differents users ?

Comment: Correct, the difference is what falls between 2.0 and the application name.  For each user it is different

Comment: If you want to deal with a batch file using the Where Command ; Just type on the cmd prompt `Where /?` it can search for the whole path of your application

Comment: would prefer if at all possible to avoid batch files and having to enter anything in a prompt if possible :)  This is just a single part of a larger script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try for this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,fso,Location,FileName,Command,Result,ReadFile,Contents
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Location=Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\AppData\Local\2.0")
FileName="2RingIPPSClient.exe"
Command = "Cmd /C Where /r "& Location &" "& FileName &" > %Tmp%\Found.txt"
Result = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
Set ReadFile = fso.OpenTextFile (Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Tmp%\Found.txt"), 1)
Contents = ReadFile.ReadLine
'wscript.echo Contents
Ws.run Contents
```

Comment: That worked!  Is there away to avoid user involvement so they dont have to hit "ok" on the notification so that the app can just run?

Comment: Just get rid of wscript.echo

Comment: Works perfect, exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for the file with a recursive function like this:

```
Function FindFile(name, fldr)
    For Each f In fldr.Files
        If f.Name = name Then
            res = f.Path
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If IsEmpty(res) Then
        For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
            res = FindFile(name, sf)
            If res <> "" Then Exit For
        Next
    End If

    FindFile = res
End Function

Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

cmd = FindFile("2RingIPPSClient.exe", fso.GetFolder(sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local\2.0")))

If cmd <> "" Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, sorry as I am a newb with scripting...  After the application is found, where would I place the execution of the file?  Would this be placed @ "do stuff?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers You should use `End Function` not `End Sub` ;)

Comment: How do I execute the 2RingIPPSClient.exe after the script above finds the file location?

Comment: @Bryan The same way you did before. And yes, it belongs where the "do stuff" comment is in my sample code.